# Is there any poker online software which run on Linux?

Tags: online

That's it. If so, which do you recommend?

Comment: are u specifically looking for installed software ?

Comment: @Morpheus Indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I play on Poker Stars. Their software runs on wine just fine.

Answer (score 2):

[NoIQ Poker](http://aff.noiq.com/?affiliate=GRINDERS) offers both 32-bit and 64-bit Linux versions of their poker client, alongside the more common Windows and Mac versions. They are not available to US players.

Answer (score 2):

```
yum info jpoker
jpoker is a client for playing online poker which runs in a Web
        : browser. It displays the list of poker tables, and when the user
        : choses one, it is displayed in the browser. The user can join the
        : game and play hands. It supports multi table tournaments. The
        : poker server to which jpoker connects must implement a protocol
        : compatible with http://pokersource.info/poker-network/.

yum info pokerth
Description : PokerTH is a poker game written in C++/QT4. You can play the
        : popular "Texas Hold'em" poker variant against up to six
        : computer-opponents or play network games with people all over the
        : world. This poker engine is available for Linux, Windows, and
        : MacOSX.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several.  In addition to NoIQ that Jeffrey Blake mentioned, any poker site developed using a closs-platform technology shall work both on Windows, OS X and Linux.

For example Winamax (ex-OnGame skin, now available in France and for every European player that is not restricted to its own country) is now using the Adobe AIR platform.

So Winamax works everywhere the Adobe AIR platform is available, including on Linux.

Then there are also several rooms allowing to play directly from your browser: using either Flash or Java applets.  The user experience might not be that great but at least it's "something available".  *(edit: I just now read your comment that you're after installed software, so playing from your browser is obviously not what you're after... But Adobe AIR mentioned above definitely counts as installed software)*

Answer (score 0):

I think nowadays you can run any poker software using wine. They usually don't need big frameworks like .NET or usually they download the required libraries for themselves, so I suggest you to try the desired poker software using WINE.

Answer (score 0):

i used to play pokerstars using WINE, prior to blackfriday and it worked pretty well, so if you live outside the USA that should work. Right now i use a virtual machine with a windows 7 guest and play lock poker... i know thats not exactly running on linux... but its an option.